# Android - updating a list adapter creates a NullPointException

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity which has an adapter that crashes.  Here is the code that crashes the program:

```
Question q = new Question ();
q.setQuestion( "" );

questions.add(q);       

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this, R.layout.user_question_list, 
        R.id.label,  questions);
```

Here is how I create the adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter; 

ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList <Question>( );
```

and the list xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

and the overall Activity xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >    


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question_label"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Loading your questions..."
    />     

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>

        <Button  
            android:id="@+id/add_question"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Ask a Question"
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">  
        </Button>     

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea why the code where I try to update the adapter results in the NullPointerException?

Here is the error log:

```
04-06 18:43:19.626: D/AndroidRuntime(2564): Shutting down VM
04-06 18:43:19.626: W/dalvikvm(2564): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-06 18:43:19.686: E/AndroidRuntime(2564):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is how the beginning of the Activity looks like:

```
public class MyQuestionsActivity extends ListActivity
{
    ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter;     

    ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList <Question>( );        

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.users_questions);

        // Make sure the user is logged in
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( MyQuestionsActivity.this);
        final String user_id = prefs.getString( "user_id" , null );     

        // If the user is not logged in, send them to log in
        if ( user_id == null )
        {
            sendEmail("My Questions Error", "User id is empty but they chose the my-questions button. They should be logged in before they see this button. Here is their user_id: " + user_id );       

            Intent loginIntent = new Intent( MyQuestionsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            MyQuestionsActivity.this.startActivity(loginIntent);            
        }          

        final TextView question_label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_label);

        Question q = new Question ();
        q.setQuestion( "" );

        questions.add(q);       

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this, R.layout.user_question_list, 
                R.id.label,  questions);

        setListAdapter ( adapter );

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        ...
```

Here are the fields for the Question class:

```
public String questionId;
public String question;
public ArrayList <QuestionComment>  questionComments;
public String questionByMemberId;
public String authorName;
```

Thanks!!

Comment: post error log. It will help more..

Comment: @user370305 I just added the error log to the bottom of the original post.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your Question class also..?

Comment: @raju just added the fields for the Question class and there are all the getters and setters for these.  Also the toString returns the question string.

Comment: okok.. that was my doubt..if it had to Strting or not..

Comment: And if you are not adding that "q" in questions list.. its is working fine?right?

Comment: @raju it only works if I get rid of the adapter code like         questions.add(q);

Comment: can u share the code of this user_question_list.xml?

Comment: @user370305 I posted it as a part of my question. Its that small xml snippet up there :)

Comment: @Shubhayu its posted up there. Its the small xml snippet of a few lines.

Comment: @user370305  public void setQuestion(String question) {
  this.question = question; }

Comment: I can't spot this R.id.label. It looks to me that, the adapter is trying to create the view and put ure question in the label but it cant find it

Comment: Have you try adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this, R.layout.user_question_list, questions); this?

Comment: @Shubhayu what do you mean? In the larger xml file there is no reference to the list?

Comment: Hmmm, I thought this snippet in the larger xml file takes care of the label:     <ListView
 android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>

Comment: Oh that worked!!! I did this: adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this, R.layout.user_question_list, questions);  and it worked. Maybe post is as the solution and I'll accept!

Comment: So. R.id.label was ure problem :) In the current implementation you don't specify the resource which is used to display the question and the adapter takes care of it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this,

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Question>(this, R.layout.user_question_list, questions);
```

And let me know what happen..

Answer (score 0):

try changing the android:id="@android:id/list" to android:id="@android:id/mylist" if you are not extending ListActivity and also paste you activity code

```
setListAdapter ( adapter ); 
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

try by reodering it like bwlow::

```
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setListAdapter ( adapter );
```

Comment: @Agrawal I am extending ListActivity and I just pasted some of the Activity.  Any idea what migth be wrong there? Thanks!

Comment: @Agrawal thanks but what does reordering them do? I tried it, but it didn't do the trick :(